# Codecademy help, Javascript

Tags: javascript

Despite my best efforts, I can't seem to get this question correct and I keep getting errors. Seeing as the Codecademy forums are a bit slow, I figured I would post here.

This is the question I'm working on:
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Here is the code I have input:

```
// Write your function below. 
// Don't forget to call your function!

var sleepCheck = function(numHours)
{
    if (sleepCheck >= 8); {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};

console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

**Thank you to everybody who answered for your input, my issue has been taken care of.**

Comment: `if (sleepCheck >= 8); <--- semicolon` "and I keep getting errors" --- it makes sense to always provide what you have, it's you who want to help us helping you.

Comment: It should also be numHours, unless you really intend to feed the variable into itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sleepCheck >= 8); {
```

Change that to

```
if (numHours >= 8) {
```

Comment: This is correct^: *"Inside the function, write an if statement where if the **number of hours** of sleep is greater than or equal to 8"*... But really... This is a problem of not following instructions, not coding.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl: I agree with your point, but the thing is that **every** (like **every every**) programming problem is in its roots caused by not following some instructions/requirements

Comment: Ah I see, I noticed that I did notice that I used sleepCheck instead of numHours, but I didn't notice the semicolon. Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It was actually a coding issue. Albeit an issue caused by a beginners mistake.

Comment: @Cyber Hamlet: it was an attention issue to be precise.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded condescending, but I was just pointing out the error of loss of transcription from instruction to code. For all we know, that tutorial could have been non-accessible to us, so we would not have known the ***exact issue***. Of course, there was a tiny issue with the semi-colon, but I guess that that was to be expected.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It's no problem. I am very much a newbie, and I'm not always aware of what I should provide. I had hoped it would be somewhat self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

In your if condition you are calling the parameter and not the name function

name function = sleepCheck 
function = numHours

in if statement you need to call the name of the function see

```js
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if(numHours >= 8){
        return"You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else{
        return"Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}

console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not working is because you are comparing the function itself with 8. The right way is to compare the parameter that you pass to the function.

When you call `sleepCheck(10)` you need to asses if 10 > 8 rather than sleepCheck > 8.

So the correct way is to say is

```
if (numHours >= 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sleepCheck >= 8); {
```

**Should be changed to:**

```
if (numHours >= 8)
{
```

*Remove the semicolon and you should use the parameter i.e. `numHours` for comparison and not the function name i.e. `sleepCheck`